# Экспортировать содержимое экрана в документ

Tags: android, c#, ios, xamarin

В приложении имеется несколько экранов с динамическим контентом. Какие существуют способы перенести содержимое этих экранов в документ (например, в Word, Excel, PDF, изображение или хотя бы какой-то другой формат, кроме txt, который впоследствии можно было открыть и удобно читать на компьютере либо телефоне). Интересуют любые возможные варианты.

Пробовал EPPlus, но, видимо, т.к. он использует библиотеки офиса, поработать с ним в рамках мобильного приложения не получится. DocX, подозреваю, также использует эти библиотеки. С PDFSharp дела не заладились, View-элементы просто не отрисовываются в файле.

Comment: ИЗ View легко  bitmap сделать, а его картинкой сохранить.

Comment: @Михаил и как?) в принципе, такой способ подойдет

Comment: Вот тут смотри - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot

Comment: @Михаил очень хорошо. а как насчет того, что в тегах указан xamarin?